# SQL order pivot result by month

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I need to order the rows based on a month or order rather than alphabecially.

When I run the query below I get the following result

```
Col Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
--- --- --- --- --- ---
Feb 1   2   3   4   5
Jan 2   3   4   5   6 
Mar 3   4   5   6   7
```

How can I order it as follows:

```
Col Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
--- --- --- --- --- ---
Jan 2   3   4   5   6 
Feb 1   2   3   4   5
Mar 3   4   5   6   7
```

My query:

```
select *
from
(
  select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek,
    col, 
    value
  from DataTable
  cross apply 
  (
    values ('Jan', JData), ('Feb', FData),  ('Mar', MData)
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for dateweek in (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)
) piv
```

At the moment I'm replacing the value's line as:

```
values ('1.Jan', JData), ('2.Feb', FData),  ('3.Mar', MData)
```

I guess there is a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from DataTable
order by convert(datetime, '2012/'+ Col +'/01')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10b1d/1/0)

Comment: Thank, that is great!! Is it possible to do order it when values are not date, for example: values ('Car', JData), ('Bus', FData),  ('Bike', MData)

Comment: Second part is a question?

Comment: Yes, your code works great for dates, but how can you order when values are not dates, like:values ('Car', JData), ('Bus', FData), ('Bike', MData)?

Comment: @Selrac: Your question, however, was specifically about ordering by month. If you wanted custom ordering in general, you should have said so.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Wawrzyniec Sz., I figure it out the solution. Adding an additional column does the trick.

For months the code will be as follows:

```
select col, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
from
(
  select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek, 
    ord,
    col, 
    value
  from DataTable
  cross apply 
  (
    values ('1','Jan', AVol_Offered), ('2','Feb', OVol_Offered),  ('3','Mar', AAHT)
  ) c (ord, col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for dateweek in (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)
) piv
order by ord
```

This would apply to other values, for example, if I want to maintain the order listed as C,A,B (which you can not order it asc or des) you will can also use the same code as follows:

```
select col, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
from
(
  select LEFT(datename(dw,datetime),3) as DateWeek, 
    ord,
    col, 
    value
  from DataTable
  cross apply 
  (
    values ('1','C', AVol_Offered), ('2','A', OVol_Offered),  ('3','B', AAHT)
  ) c (ord, col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for dateweek in (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)
) piv
order by ord
```

Thanks for the help/hints